# Assertion in numpy.add.reduce

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have been racking my brain for a while to find the implementation of numpy.add.reduce so that I can add assertion to find numerical bugs for floating point addition and subtraction. I have located the code to the file reduction.c and I am assuming context->method->get_strided_loop to be the method which is dynamically assigned according to ufunc name and dtype. Can you expand on that and help me figure out how I can find the actual code ? Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What kind of 'assertion' do you expect to add?  This is `c` code that goes through a complex `numpy` specific precompile step.  I imagine the 'reduce' code is general and works with many `ufunc` - add, subtract, multiply, even logical operations. This is more of a `numpy` development topic than a SO debugging one.

Comment: Also why kind(s) of numerical bugs are you looking for?  Are you sure that digging into the `c` code will help?  It might help if you showed a [mcve] that produced the bug.  It's more likely that that there's a bug in your python code than in compiled methods.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.